# Pandas Groupby Conditional Aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say you have a dataframe as follows:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2019]*5+[2020]*5,
          'Month': [1,1,2,2,3]*2,
          'Hour': [0,1,2,3,4]*2,
          'Value': [0.2,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.1,0.2]})
```

Then, set "low" times to be hours between 1 and 3 (inclusive), and "high" times to be all other hours (in this case, hours 0 and 4).  What I would like to do is get the average `Value` for the "low" and "high" times for each `Year` and `Month`.  Ideally, these would be appended as new columns to the groupby() dataframe (i.e., the final dataframe would have `Year`, `Month`, `Low`, and `High` columns).

For loops work, but they're not ideal.  I could also create a dummy variable (for instance, 0s and 1s) to signify the "low" and "high" times in the dataframe to groupby.  However, it seems to me that there should be some way to use Pandas groupby(['Year', 'Month']).agg(...) to achieve the result in an efficient/optimal way.  I haven't had any luck thus far using groupby+agg, mainly because agg() uses only a series (not the remaining dataframe), so one can't use a conditional within agg based on the `Hour` to calculate the average `Value`.

Expected result from sample data:

`Year   Month   High    Low
0   2019    1       0.2     0.30
1   2019    2       NaN     0.15
2   2019    3       0.4     NaN
3   2020    1       0.3     0.20
4   2020    2       NaN     0.30
5   2020    3       0.2     NaN`

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Read your question wrong first time, If I understand you want 4 rows in the end? For  each year in combination with each month. Is that correct? See my answer for output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) after creating a low/high type indicator field:

```
data['Type'] = np.where(data['Hour'].between(1,3), 'Low', 'High')

pvt_df = (pd.pivot_table(data, index=['Year', 'Month'], 
                         columns='Type', values='Value', aggfunc=np.mean)
            .reset_index()
            .rename_axis(None, axis='columns')
         )    

print(pvt_df)
#    Year  Month  High   Low
# 0  2019      1   0.2  0.30
# 1  2019      2   NaN  0.15
# 2  2019      3   0.4   NaN
# 3  2020      1   0.3  0.20
# 4  2020      2   NaN  0.30
# 5  2020      3   0.2   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not win the price for most beautiful piece of code, but if I understand you correctly, this is what you want.

(correct me if im wrong since theres no expected output included)

`Groupby` 4 times and concat the years and months together.
After that do a final merge to get all the columns together

```
low_hours = [1, 2, 3]

groupby1 = data[data.Hour.isin(low_hours)].groupby('Year').Value.mean().reset_index().rename({'Value':'Value_year_low'},axis=1)
groupby2 = data[~data.Hour.isin(low_hours)].groupby('Year').Value.mean().reset_index().rename({'Value':'Value_year_high'},axis=1).drop('Year', axis=1)
groupby3 = data[data.Hour.isin(low_hours)].groupby(['Year','Month']).Value.mean().reset_index().rename({'Value':'Value_month_low'},axis=1)
groupby4 = data[~data.Hour.isin(low_hours)].groupby(['Year','Month']).Value.mean().reset_index().rename({'Value':'Value_month_high'},axis=1).drop(['Year','Month'], axis=1)

df_final1 = pd.concat([groupby1, groupby2], axis=1)
df_final2 = pd.concat([groupby3, groupby4], axis=1)

df_final = pd.merge(df_final1, df_final2, on='Year')
print(df_final)
   Year  Value_year_low  Value_year_high  Month  Value_month_low  \
0  2019        0.200000             0.30      1             0.30   
1  2019        0.200000             0.30      2             0.15   
2  2020        0.266667             0.25      1             0.20   
3  2020        0.266667             0.25      2             0.30   

   Value_month_high  
0               0.2  
1               0.4  
2               0.3  
3               0.2
```

Comment: Yes.  The resulting dataframe should have four rows: 2019/1, 2019/2, 2020/1, 2020/2.  However, there should only be four columns in the result: `Year`, `Month`, `Low`, and `High`.  So, the `Low` and `High` values should be the average for that month and year for their respective hours.

Comment: Which are in my output `Value_month_low` & `Value_month_high`, only the names are wrong. Correct? If yes, I will edit answer with correct output. @rhozzy

Comment: Yes, it looks like those values are correct.  However, where are the results for month 3?  Also, this answer doesn't really get at an efficient/optimal way to do this, as far as I can tell...